# ExpressJS folder structure

Tags: node.js, express, directory-structure

I currently follow the structure generated by Express-Generator but I doubt that's the best practice. Is there any other folder structure that you are using and why you use it?

Comment: I have been using the same structure for my projects but I haven't yet faced any issues with it. You may want to separate your middleware functions or other functions in separate packages though.

Comment: http://www.tutorialsavvy.com/2015/08/node-express-application-with-webstorm.html/